# OCaml "include Module" only includes functions exposed by the interface

Tags: module, include, ocaml

I'm trying to test an OCaml module, called `Game`. However, the initialize function for `Game`, when used in the normal context of my project, only accepts a few parameters. This means certain tests would require me to init `Game`, then perform a specific combination of hundreds of operations just to get to a desired state, which is infeasible.

My idea was to create a new init function that allows the user to hard-code every component of a `Game` object. Since it'll only be used for testing, it seems like a bad idea to make this init function be part of the typical mli interface, so I thought using the keyword `include` in my `testGame.ml` file would help.

In my `testGame.ml`, both `generate_player_ids` and the `Game.t` type are "unbound," even though I define them in `test.ml`. This must be because they aren't exposed in `game.mli`, but I thought that using `include` would essentially be like copying and pasting the entire module, including the parts of the .ml file that aren't exposed. Is there a way to get `testGame.ml` to recognize these? Otherwise, what is the idiomatic way to have functions that recognize the hidden parts of a module for the purposes of testing?

testGame.ml:

```
include Game

let init_game_test
  num_players
  board
  turn
  starting_turn
  setup_rounds_left
  scoring_points
  num_rounds =
  let player_ids = generate_player_ids num_players in
  {
    players = players_of_player_ids player_ids;
    player_order = player_ids;
    board;
    turn;
    starting_turn;
    setup_rounds_left;
    scoring_points;
    num_rounds;
  }
```

game.ml:

```
type t = {
  players : (PlayerId.t * Player.t) list;
  player_order : PlayerId.t list;
  board : Board.t;
  turn : PlayerId.t;
  starting_turn : PlayerId.t;
  setup_rounds_left : int;
  scoring_points : (Cell.soil * int list) list;
  num_rounds : int;
}

let generate_player_ids num_players =
  match num_players with
  | 2 -> [ 1; 2 ]
  | 3 -> [ 1; 2; 3 ]
  | 4 -> [ 1; 2; 3; 4 ]
  | _ -> failwith "Must be 2-4 players"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're quite correct in assuming it's because they aren't exposed. `include` works on OCaml's module system, rather than a straight source inclusion basis as something like C does.

If you leave out the `.mli` interface file everything is by default exposed.

Comment: I'd rather expose as little as possible, or at least it's my intuition that that would be preferable. For now, I just have my `init_game_test` added to the `.mli`, but is there a better way?

Comment: You can specify the interface in the *.ml file. `module Game : sig ... end = struct ... end`. Having a separate *.mli file _can_ be advantageous, but maintaining the separate file when source is in an early stage of development, and a high degree of flux can be a pain.